# YAML Header for R Markdown file - Adding LaTeX packages with options throws errors (sometimes)

Tags: r, yaml, latex, reproducible-research

Following the [R Markdown Cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/latex-extra.html) (along with a number of the posts here) and I'm trying to insert a collection of LaTeX packages in the YAML header for my R Markdown file.

When I copy/paste the header from that website into my file:

```
output: 
  pdf_document:
    extra_dependencies:
      caption: ["labelfont={bf}"]
      hyperref: ["unicode=true", "breaklinks=true"]
      lmodern: null
```

I get the error: `! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package hyperref.` This only happens when I include the options in square brackets - if I remove them, everything works as expected.

In a similar instance, I tried to add the `babel` package in the same manner. When I include it like this:

```
    extra_dependencies:
      babel: ["hebrew", "english"]
```

I get the error: `! You can't use` end-group character }' after \the.`

I am even more confused (if that's possible), because when I include options for the `threeparttable` package, everything runs without issue.

Here is a file to test:

```
---
title: "R Notebook"
author: 
   - Me
date: "Last compiled on `r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B %Y')`"
output: 
  pdf_document: 
    highlight: tango
    keep_tex: yes
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
    fig_caption: yes
    extra_dependencies:
      cjhebrew: null
      babel: ["hebrew", "english"]
---


# Section 1

Test
```

When I knit this to PDF, I get the error:

! You can't use `end-group character }' after \the.
\everypar #1->\o@everypar {\rl@everypar #1}

The log file is at [this repo](https://github.com/Doc-Midnight/Test_Dir).

Comment: Can you make a [mre] that  allows us to reproduce your problem with babel?

Comment: please also show your .log file for the babel issue. Maybe you have an old version of the package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rmarkdown automatically loads the hyperref package. You can't load it again with conflicting options.

You can change its settings with `\hypersetup{...}`:

```
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
header-includes:
  - \hypersetup{breaklinks=true}
---

test
```

However are you sure you need all your options and packages?

- rmakdown already uses the `unicode` option, so no need to add it a second time
- rmarkdown also automatically loads the `lmodern` package, no need to load it again

---

The other problem is the interaction of the babel and the microtype package, which rmarkdown loads by default. With real latex, you could simply avoid loading every package but the kitchen sink and you would never have had this problem, or at least you could add the `nopatch` option directly to `microtype` (if you would really need it) ... but rmarkdown makes this unnecessarily complicate.

Here a dirty hack, hoping that no other packages also uses this name for an option:

```
---
title: "R Notebook"
author: 
   - Me
date: "Last compiled on `r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B %Y')`"
output: 
  pdf_document: 
    highlight: tango
    keep_tex: yes
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
    fig_caption: yes
    extra_dependencies:
      cjhebrew: null
      babel: ["hebrew", "english"]
classoption: "nopatch"
---


# Section 1

Test
```

Comment: I was just following the example from the book. What about the babel package with its options?

Comment: @KarlWolfschtagg I can't reproduce your problem with babel. Like I alerady asked you yesterday, make a [mre] and show your .log file. My suspicion would be an outdated version

Comment: Reproducible example posted with link to log file.

Comment: @KarlWolfschtagg Posted a hacky workaround....

Comment: I'll take a hack! I've never seen this before (although I did confirm that it works). Where can I read about this?

Comment: @KarlWolfschtagg The trick is that latex documentclasses pass on all unkown options to the packages. So even though I can't directly tell `microtype` to use the option, it will reach the package this way (... and all other package, that's why this is a bit risky)